# Arch+KDE, connect to MySQL server in local container?

Tags: linux, mysql, arch-linux, docker, mysql5

I'm running Manjaro/Arch with KDE, which uses MariaDB. I need to use MySQL specifically, so I have created a local container running MySQL 5.7. However, I cannot seem to connect to the instance running in the container.

```
> docker container list
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
a4f29115df9f        mysql:5.7.25        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql57
```

So I hoped that I could connect on port 33060, but when I do `mysql -uuser -ppass -P 33060`, I am connected to my local MariaDB instance.

Is there someone I can map a hostname to my container so I can use the `-h` parameter to specify the host?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine the IP address of my container using `docker inspect <container_name>` and then connect directly via `mysql ... -h<container_ip>`. To make this easier, I added an entry to `/etc/hosts` to map the container's IP to a more friendly hostname.